# Using postition:sticky for the bottom of a div Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Since Bootstrap 4 doesnt Support .affix anymore, i have to find a other solution for a fixed box.

I want a div Container stay fixed when you scroll to it. For now i solved it with

```
.fixedcard{
 position: sticky;
 top:75%;
}
```

Now i got the problem, that the sticky part starts from the top of my div Container. This causes the problem, that the view differentiate on smaller device. I want to fix the div Container 25% from bottom starting by the bottom of the div Container.

I tried to illustrate my problem.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle of what you've got so far?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bkctfmba/2/ * updated

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS `calc()` for it to work out `0% + height of element`.

```
.slider {
    height : 300px;
    position: sticky;
    top: calc(0% + 300px); /*Height of element*/
}
```

Comment: First i want to thank you for your solution. But this will not work for containers without fixed height.